# Test Apex class that has void as the return type

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

How to test an apex class that does not have a return value?

Here this is the test class I wrote so far. It creates two content documents and then a case, what I am testing is linking the content documents to the case. Here the method of the class being called which is ApexActionRelateFilesToCase.relateFilesToCase(caseAndFiles) has void has the return type.

```
   @isTest
public with sharing class ApexActionRelateFilesToCaseTest {
    @isTest
    public static void testSetup(){

        ContentVersion contentVersion1 = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Test_file-1',
            PathOnClient = 'Test1.jpg',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content Data'),
            IsMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert contentVersion1;

        ContentVersion contentVersion2 = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Test_file-2',
            PathOnClient = 'Test2.jpg',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content Data'),
            IsMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert contentVersion2;

        Case testCase = new Case();
        testCase.Subject ='Test file linking to case';
        insert testCase;

        List<ApexActionRelateFilesToCase.CaseIdandReleatedFiles> caseAndFiles = new List<ApexActionRelateFilesToCase.CaseIdandReleatedFiles>();
        caseAndFiles[0].caseId = testCase.Id;
        caseAndFiles[0].contentDocumentIds.add(contentVersion1.Id);
        caseAndFiles[0].contentDocumentIds.add(contentVersion2.Id);

        Test.startTest();
        ApexActionRelateFilesToCase.relateFilesToCase(caseAndFiles);
        Test.stopTest();

        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId  FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntity.Id = :testCase.Id];
        System.debug(cdl.size());
        System.assertEquals(2, cdl.size());
    }
}
```

Update - Uploading the Testing Class

```
public with sharing class ApexActionRelateFilesToCase {

   public class CaseIdandRelatedFiles {
     @InvocableVariable(label='Case Id' required=true)
     public String caseId;
     @InvocableVariable(label='ContentDocument Ids' required=true) 
     public List<String> contentDocumentIds;
   }

   @InvocableMethod(label='Attach Files to Case')
    public static void relateFilesToCase(List<CaseIdandRelatedFiles> caseIdAndFileIds) {
        System.debug(caseIdAndFileIds);
        
        if(caseIdAndFileIds.size() > 0) {//Linking uploaded files to newly created case, if user attached files
            List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocuments = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            for (String fileId: caseIdAndFileIds[0].contentDocumentIds) {
                ContentDocumentLink file = new ContentDocumentLink();
                file.ContentDocumentId = fileId;
                file.LinkedEntityId = caseIdAndFileIds[0].caseId;
                file.ShareType = 'V';
                file.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                contentDocuments.add(file);
            }
            
            try {
                Database.SaveResult[] fileAttachResults = Database.insert(contentDocuments, true);              
            } catch(System.DmlException e) {
                RecordException.recordError('ApexActionRelateFilesToCase', 'relateFilesToCase', e.getMessage());             
            }
        }
    }
      
}
```

Comment: your test method(s) should be annotated with `@isTest` instead of `@testSetup`. The testSetup annotation has a special meaning, and you should know what it's used for before attempting to use it.

Comment: @DerekF I modified and added the assert statements, still failing.

Comment: Your test needs to retrieve the ContentDocuments that are created and assert that they contain the data points that you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's very little we can tell you without seeing the class that you're trying to test (the SUT, System Under Test). The partial test class alone is insufficient.

With the little information we have so far, about the only things I can say are:

- There is often little to no difference between testing the thing you're working on, and testing a "normal" class. You still need to go through AAA. Arrange (set up your test environment), Act (call the class method you want to test), Assert.
- The main utility of unit tests is in the assertions that you make
  (coverage is a byproduct, and the only thing Salesforce can
  reasonably measure).

You use assertions to verify that the end result of running your SUT is what you expect.

The return value from a method is only one of the many possible results you can look at. Others include:

- Looking at the governor limits consumed by the SUT (cpu time, dml rows, queries used, etc...)
- Looking at the publicly visible state of your SUT (static variables, instance variables, properties)
- Seeing if your class threw a particular exception
- Looking for changes to the database (did you create an SObject record? delete an SObject record? make a modification to an existing SObject record?)

Looking at what you have so far, that last one seems like an obvious candidate (make sure that there's a `ContentDocument` or maybe `ContentDocumentLink` whose parentId matches the test Case).

Comment: Thanks Derek, as far as I can see, I guess I did everything to the best of my knowledge. The actual class I am testing here works fine. I have added the actual testing class as well to the post. The error I am seeing is System.ListException: List index out of bounds and is pointing to the line caseAndFiles[0].caseId = testCase.Id; in the test class. If you could have a look.